# Gulp plugin for running a PHP server?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm looking to transition over from grunt to gulp.  However I'm not finding a way to serve PHP files with livereload support, such as gateway (https://www.npmjs.org/package/gateway) using mounts.  Are ther any plugins out there for running/server PHP using a gulp task?

Comment: I don't understand what has livereload to do with PHP... Are you trying to "watch" some PHP files and do something with their output?

Comment: Sort of.  I want it to serve PHP files because that is what I am scripting with (using include for header, footer), but also want the benefits of sass, livereload, etc for developing the UI.

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked totally the same question few weeks ago. I want to start a native PHP server under Gulp, because I like the syntax better than Grunt. I also want to use PHP just to include other HTML files. :) It turns out there is a 'gulp-connect-php' plugn which has a very similar syntax to 'grunt-php' plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-php

Here is my code to Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    connectPHP = require('gulp-connect-php');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connectPHP.server({
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    bin: 'C:/php/php.exe',
    ini: 'C:/php/php.ini',
    port: 8000,
    base: 'dev',
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

I also setted the exe and ini file location.

If you interested in, this is the code for Grunt:

```
php: {
  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true,
      bin: 'C:/php/php.exe',
      ini: 'C:/php/php.ini',
      base: '../development',
      port: 8000
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using gulp-connect-php with http-proxy.  In the end, my php serve task looked like this:

```
gulp.task('php-serve', ['styles', 'fonts'], function () {
connect.server({
    port: 9001,
    base: 'app',
    open: false
});

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port  : 9000,
    server: {
        baseDir   : ['.tmp', 'app'],
        routes    : {
            '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
        },
        middleware: function (req, res, next) {
            var url = req.url;

            if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
                proxy.web(req, res, { target: '{ip address taken out}:9001' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    }
});

// watch for changes
gulp.watch([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
]).on('change', reload);

gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```