# Connect to Homebrew PHP/MySQL from Angular App using $http

Tags: php, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am building an Angular App with Gulp locally on my dev machine, that will eventually be a SaaS. All the data is hardcoded JSON in a service purely to get the front-end working.

Now I am ready to connect to a local database and will use PHP/MySQL.
I have a local development environment on OSX setup with Homebrew that has PHP and MySQL ready to go.

**The issue:**
I get a 404 when I use the `url: 'db-insert.php'` line no matter where I put the db-insert.php file in my directory structure.

`POST http://localhost:3000/db-insert.php 404 (Not Found)`

```
   var request = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'db-insert.php',
    data: {
        name: $scope.name,
        email: $scope.email,
        message: $scope.message
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

I have investigated

• CORS: Tried `open -a 'Google Chrome' --args -allow-file-access-from-files`

• [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php)

• [gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990781/gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php)

• [BrowserSync Proxies](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/)

The app uses Gulps BrowserSync which has a proxy option that leverages Express to connect to a defined middleware, but I am stumped at where to point it or if it is the correct option at all.

Any explanation of what the correct way to do this is would be great. I think the answer is probably a combination of what I have found, but the implementation is the issue. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This turned out to be a filesystem/CORS issue. Here is how I solved it:

**1) Go through the server to get to the php file**

http://127.0.0.1/dev/db-insert.php

**NOT**

file://myproject/dev/db-insert.php

I was trying to access the file directly in the file system and not by its URL on the PHP server I have running as my localhost. When I changed the url to go through the apache server to find the file, it was able find it.

**2) Once I got to the file I got the CORS issue**

Adding the code below to the top of db-insert.php executes allowed the file to be accessed.The server could then execute the code.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header('Access-Control-Request-Method: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *,x-requested-with,Content-Type');
    header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
```

Comment: You can use BrowserSync middleware to add those CORS headers. `middleware: function (req, res, next) { res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); next(); }` If they're only used for testing environment and won't be needed in production.