# Gulp PHP with BrowserSync and a proxy server throwing error

Tags: php, node.js, gulp, http-proxy, browser-sync

I had to redownload all of my dev tools after upgrading/reset on Windows 10.  I can't seem to get my server working with gulp-connect-php, gulp-browser-sync, and http-proxy.  The task (below) is actually from this answer:  [Gulp-webapp running BrowserSync and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990781/gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php).

This is on top of a generation of gulp-webapp from Yeoman.  The regular "serve" works, but of course doesn't spin up PHP files.  I had it working before the upgrade, but now the http-proxy errors out with an ECONNREFUSED when I try to bring up the URL. Note that it doesn't error out until I actually go to the URL, if the task is setup to not open the browser automatically, it won't error until I go to localhost:3000.

Any ideas the cause of this error?

**Gulp Task**

```
gulp.task('php-serve', ['styles', 'fonts'], () => {
  phpConnect.server({
    port: 9001,
    base: 'app',
    open: false
  });
  const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    open: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      },
      middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        var url = req.url;
        if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
          proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001' });
        }
        else {
          next();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
  ]).on('change', reload);

  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

**Gulp Run Task with Error**

```
$ gulp php-serve
[07:30:09] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[07:30:11] Using gulpfile ~\...\gulpfile.babel.js
[07:30:11] Starting 'styles'...
[07:30:12] Starting 'fonts'...
[07:30:12] Finished 'styles' after 1.08 s
[07:30:12] Finished 'fonts' after 306 ms
[07:30:12] Starting 'php-serve'...
[07:30:12] Finished 'php-serve' after 183 ms

[BS] Access URLs:
----------------------------------
Local: http://localhost:9000
External: http://x.x.x.x:9000
----------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://x.x.x.x:3001
----------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: .tmp
[BS] Serving files from: app

C:\...\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:119

throw err;
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

Comment: Any news on this?

I am running into the same problem except that I implemented this solution https://github.com/micahblu/gulp-connect-php/issues/2#issuecomment-124124307 But the same error ECONNREFUSED

The thing is that is does work at some (Also windows 10) but at work it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bad install of http-proxy and/or gulp-php-connect.  I uninstalled them, cleared npm cache, and did a fresh install.  Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the reason.

Check or you have php installed on your machine and added to your path variables.

open your command line and type:

```
$ php --version
```

If it returns:

```
sh.exe": php: command not found
```

It means it is not installed or not in the path variable.

You can install php by simply installing WAMP/XAMP or MAMP
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

To make sure it is in your path I like to use patheditor
https://patheditor2.codeplex.com/

There go through these simple steps
1) open Path Editor
2) click 'add' in the 'user' section
3) search the folder where php.exe is. (usually something like: C:/xampp/php)
4) click 'ok' and 'ok' again to close path editor
5) reopen your commandline tool and you will see that $ php --version will find the php.exe

Try to run your gulp task again. It should work!

Comment: It was actually a bad install of http-proxy and/or gulp-php-connect. I cleared npm cache and did a fresh install, started working.

Comment: Good to hear you solved the issue to. I Think You should add your solution as an answer as well so others can benefit from it in the future. I'll leave mine here as it might helps others.