# Setting up Yeoman Webapp with PHP

Tags: php, generator, yeoman, browser-sync

Trying to set up yo webapp to use a PHP server instead of HTML.

I tried following this answer by example with no success. 
[Gulp-webapp running BrowserSync and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990781/gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php)

I added [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php) to my project.

```
// Towards the top of my gulpfile, added: 
const connect = require('gulp-connect-php');

// Added the following task below: 

gulp.task('php-serve', ['styles', 'fonts'], function () {
connect.server({
    port: 9001,
    base: 'app',
    open: false
});

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port  : 9000,

    server: {
        baseDir   : ['.tmp', 'app'],
        routes    : {
            '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
        },
        middleware: function (req, res, next) {
            var url = req.url;

            if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
                proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    }
});

// watch for changes
gulp.watch([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
]).on('change', reload);

gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

Ran `gulp php-serve`

```
PHP 5.5.36 Development Server started [etc…]
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:9001
```

However, not without error:

```
ReferenceError: httpProxy is not defined
```

How can this be resolved? I wouldn't even mind using MAMP which I already have running on port 8888

Answer (score 3):

It seems I missed a vital part of installing http-proxy, which I thought I had installed before.

Here's an idiot guide of getting PHP to work with the most popular yeoman generator, generator webapp, with big thanks to [TobyG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081459/tobyg)

Install [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#installation)

```
npm install http-proxy --save
```

Install [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php)

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-connect-php
```

Add these two functions to the top of *gulpfile.js*

```
const connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
```

Add this additional task to *gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('php-serve', ['styles', 'fonts'], function () {
connect.server({
    port: 9001,
    base: 'app',
    open: false
});

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port  : 9000,
    server: {
        baseDir   : ['.tmp', 'app'],
        routes    : {
            '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
        },
        middleware: function (req, res, next) {
            var url = req.url;

            if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
                proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    }
});

// watch for changes
gulp.watch([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
]).on('change', reload);

gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

Comment: It works. I had to change some bits in the html task in my gulpfile: from `return gulp.src('app/*.html')` to `return gulp.src(['app/*.html', 'app/*.php'])` in order to compile the js and css called from the php files to the dist folder.

Comment: Also you have to do the same edit in the wiredep task.

Comment: In case you have updated the generator-webapp to 2.3.2 onwards you would need to change one extra line in the suggested code. Change `browserSync({...` to `browserSync.init({`in order to avoid the error `browserSync is not a function...`