# How to use browser sync with php

Tags: php, gulp, xampp, gulp-browser-sync

I would like to use Browsersync with PHP, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Currently I am using Gulp. Is it possible to either use Browsersync with XAMPP/MAMP, or use a Gulp plugin to read `.php` files?

Comment: It can be done with Gulp. Check [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990781/gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php). Please remember to search for similar questions before opening a new question of your own. I'd also recommend checking  [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and taking the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 6):

use gulp-connect-php

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-connect-php
```

then setup you gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
   browserSync({
     proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
       });
    });

    gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', function () {
      browserSync.reload();
    });
});
```

see documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php

Also there is a good tutorial here https://phpocean.com/tutorials/front-end/automate-your-workflow-with-gulp-part-3-live-reloading/23

Comment: The tutorial you link to is for gulp 3, which will break when combined with gulp 4. The current stable version. Still looking for a good v4 tutorial for gulp-connect-php combined with other handy gulp options. As the wrong port and base dir are served in my case...

Answer (score 4):

I have the same situation for a few days until I figure out that it happens because I didn't close my html output properly. BrowserSync needs to include some javascript text before to reload the browser. If the **html**, **body** tags are *NOT closed* or *NOT present*, BrowserSync has **nowhere** to include the script.

Answer (score 0):

A `proxy` option is now available in browser-sync when using an external server.

Config docs : https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-proxy

```js
// Using a vhost-based url
proxy: "local.dev"

// Using a localhost address with a port
proxy: "localhost:8888"

// Using localhost sub directories
proxy: "localhost/site1"
```

Command line : https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line#start

```
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost:8080" --files "**/*"
```